# How do you populate a Magento_UI dynamicRows element?

Tags: uicomponent, magento2.2

I've got a `<dynamicRows>` element.  When I render the object, I'm able to create new rows, and all of the fields appear.

However, I have no idea how to:

1. Populate the rows from the database
2. Save the rows back into the database

I've been looking at `vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_attribute_add_form.xml` as a reference, and the only element that looks remotely like "data" is:

```
<item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="swatch_text" xsi:type="string">swatch_text</item>
</item>
```

But I can't figure out how that works, and what the "swatch_text"  parameter does.

I've also added a `<dataProvider>` tag, but I'm not sure where to add it.  I've added my UI xml below:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
<button>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="displayAsLink" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Test</item>
            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.business_card_modal</item>
                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">toggleModal</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</button>
<modal name="business_card_modal">
    <settings>
        <options>
            <option name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="text" xsi:type="string">Done</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-primary</item>
                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.name }</item>
                            <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">actionDone</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </option>
            <option name="title" xsi:type="string">Business Card?</option>
        </options>
        <onCancel>actionDone</onCancel>
        <dataScope>data.product</dataScope>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="mm_bizcard_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validateUrl path="catalog/product_attribute/validate"/>
            <submitUrl path="catalog/product_attribute/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="MM\Bizcard\Model\Product\DataProvider" name="mm_bizcard_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>attribute_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="my_fieldset" class="MM\Bizcard\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="swatch_text" xsi:type="string">swatch_text</item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Bizcard Thing 2</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <dynamicRows name="bizcard">
            <settings>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Label</addButtonLabel>
                <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">attribute_options.position</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="testfield" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">option.order</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <visible>true</visible>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <field name="position" component="Magento_Catalog/js/form/element/input" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="prefixName" xsi:type="string">option.order</item>
                            <item name="prefixElementName" xsi:type="string">option_</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <additionalClasses>
                            <class name="_hidden">true</class>
                        </additionalClasses>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <visible>false</visible>
                        <dataScope>position</dataScope>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">100</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
    </fieldset>
</modal>
</form>
```

How do I populate `<dynamicRows>` with data on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<form>` element seems to be missing it's configuration. You should have something like this:

```
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">some_form.your_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">some_form.your_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Some Form</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">some_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            ...
        </item>
    </argument>
```

Where 'your_data_source' is the name supplied to the `<dataSource>`

The `provider` argument to the `js_config` is what makes the data source visible to the form.

Also, `<dataSource>` should be under `<form>`, not `<modal>`